# Pressing Enter Key Randomly on my JavaFx application Triggers wrong Button action

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Pressing Enter Key on my javaFx application triggers wrong button,
In this case it triggers the logout button
What exactly could be the problem.

FXML Excerpt

```
<VBox layoutX="7.0" layoutY="160.0" prefHeight="407.0" prefWidth="174.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="160.0">
  <children>
    <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="180.0" text="Add Account" textFill="#c94949" underline="true" />
    <Button defaultButton="true" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="180.0" text="Account List" textAlignment="CENTER" underline="true" wrapText="true">
    <VBox.margin>
    <Insets top="10.0" />
     </VBox.margin>
    </Button>
    <Button fx:id="logoutButton" onAction="#logoutButtonAccount" defaultButton="true" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="180.0" text="Logout" textAlignment="CENTER" underline="true" wrapText="true">
    <VBox.margin>
   <Insets top="10.0" />
  </VBox.margin>
  </Button>
  </children>
  </VBox>
```

The Function called

```
    public void logoutButtonAccount(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

        loginManager.logout();
        println(actionEvent.getSource().toString());

    }
```

But randomly pressing enter on my application triggers this and logout the application. Any help or suggestions is highly appreciated.

I tried to print out the event source it still saying it's from the logoutButton

OUTPUT:

```
Button[id=logoutButton, styleClass=button]'Logout'
Button[id=logoutButton, styleClass=button]'Logout'
Button[id=logoutButton, styleClass=button]'Logout'
Button[id=logoutButton, styleClass=button]'Logout'
```

These are the outcome after pressing enter multiple times without clicking on the button.
Thanks for your advice or suggesstion in advance.

Comment: TL;DR It seems to me that your button is set to default, so whenever you press enter, the `logoutButtonAccount` will be called.

Comment: Thanks @zlakad. It worked! Let me mark this post as answered

Comment: Just go on, and good luck... I don't really care about the reputation.

Answer (score 2):

The attribute value defaultButton="true" is what caused it.

change it to false or eliminating the attribute solves it.

```
    <Button fx:id="logoutButton" onAction="#logoutButtonAccount" defaultButton="false" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="180.0" text="Logout" textAlignment="CENTER" underline="true" wrapText="true">

 <VBox.margin>
    <Insets top="10.0" />
 </VBox.margin>

</Button>
```

Just as @zlakad noticed.